# How to keep records of past week visits in a web app?

Tags: database-design, mariadb, change-tracking

I am developing a newspaper-like MVC webapp with an article content type which has a visits field. The database is MariaDB.

Each time a visitor requests an article, the visits field of the article row is incremented by 1. So I can easily query articles by their overall visits.

But what I want is to sort out articles based on number of visits which each article has got in the past week.

I thought to have a separate table like `weekly-stats` in which I can insert and increment article info with their recent visits upon each request, but then I need to empty the table weekly as a cron job, which is not ideal, and it leaves the stats empty after the data is being purged.

I also thought of having articles' visits saved in an expiring cache like redis and set the cached records to expire after a week, but then it brings all the complexities of inserting and querying redis hash elements.

So I thought there might be some more straightforward design strategies that I miss. How can I achieve this with the least hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each time a visitor requests an article, the visits field of the article row is incremented by 1. So I can easily query articles by their overall visits. [...] **But what I want is to sort out articles based on number of visits which each article has got in the past week.**

You can do it that way. I would record the visitors id though, unless you're getting too much traffic to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE article_visits (
  article_id  int REFERENCES article,
  user_id     int REFERENCES users,
  ts_visit    timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
);
CREATE INDEX ON article_visits ( article_id, ts_visit );

SELECT article_id, count(*)
FROM article AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN article_visits USING (article_id)
WHERE ts_visit > now() - interval '1 week' -- PostgreSQL has intervals.
GROUP BY article_id;
```

I would use PostgreSQL. On MySQL you'll have to use their goofy proprietary [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), and [`WEEKOFYEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear). Who knows what they're thinking here. They hate standards.

Comment: Great, but how would you clean up the `article_visits` table? It gets increasingly costly to query as the logs grow bigger day by day.

Comment: MySQL has had support for the interval feature for ages, see e.g. [the doc for 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: And since the question was actually about MariaDB: Yes, [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date-and-time-units/) too, obviously.

Comment: @Babr: this should not be a significant issue *if* the table has appropriate indexes and the filtering & joining clauses of your queries are not written in a way that would block the use of those indexes. If indexes are appropriately used reading from a table with double the number of rows will take at must one or two extra page reads (add at most an extra page or two each time the table doubles in size).

Answer (score 1):

The `weekly_stats` table can have one record for every week, i.e. something like:

```
CREATE TABLE weekly_stats (
  week_start date PRIMARY_KEY, -- e.g. '2018-03-05'
  article_id int unsigned,
  view_count int unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT week_stats_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (article_id) 
    REFERENCES `article` (`article_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Your application will then have update the `weekly_stats.view_count` every time an article is viewed. If the record for that particular week doesn't exist, the application will have to create it.

If you want to delete old data, which may not be necessary: Instead of a cron job, you could use a MariaDB event. Set it up to only delete records older than some limit, e.g. 365 days.

Comment: There are no `week_start` dates. by `last week` I mean the last 24x7 hours.

Comment: @Babr OK, I see. But you could save space by grouping view counts together in chunks as in my example. If not by week, then perhaps by day or by hour? Do you really need to store the exact timestamp of every viewing?

Comment: I think maybe the main problem with this approach, though, is that you don't record the IP addresses, so you can't count _unique_ views. If that's what you want, then my solution won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to be deleting the data, you might want to keep it for comparing with next week, or next year, or for looking at this month's visits rather than this week's.

I would have thought a log table would be more what you are wanting: one row per request containing the article ID and a timestamp. If your users are authenticated then a user ID too. Then you can count the visits for this calendar week, the rolling week, last week, this month, the month two months go, and so on, with simple aggregate queries. If this proves inefficient on each read despite good index choices because the number of visits is huge, *then* think about the complexities of caching results and/or processing them in a separate reporting database instead of the live one.

Once the data gets large then you might want to consider archiving off old data, but that may be far in the future. Assuming each row has a 32-bit integer article ID, an 8-byte datetime value for the timestamp, and a large (8-byte integer) value as the primary key, and an index on article ID, a million views is going to take of the order of 32Mbyte of space. Even using 128-bit UUID values instead of integers for everything that'll be of the order of 72Mbyte per million logged requests.

To consider the query efficiency of keeping the log data for longer, I've done a quick test populating tables with random data for 100 articles that get 1000 reads per day (so a total of 10,000 requests per day being logged). Arranging tables containing one month worth of data and one year worth running the following queies:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM onemonth WHERE articleID = 42 AND timeOfReq BETWEEN '2018-02-28' AND '2018-03-08'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oneyear  WHERE articleID = 42 AND timeOfReq BETWEEN '2018-02-28' AND '2018-03-08'
```

results in `1919` and `1920` pages being accessed respectively. The data is about 12 times larger but the query only 0.06% slower. The same is seen with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM onemonth WHERE timeOfReq BETWEEN '2018-02-28' AND '2018-03-08'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oneyear  WHERE timeOfReq BETWEEN '2018-02-28' AND '2018-03-08'
```

and would also with more complex queries with grouping, aggregation, and joins to elsewhere. The resulting tables (including indexes) were 220MByte and 2.5GByte in size respectively. This was in MS SQL Server (using the output from `SET STATISICS IO ON` to gauge the work being done for each query) but you will see similar results with other databases. I didn't use any tricks like row/page compression to reduce the data size though I suspect they would be quite effective with this data.